# How do I reuse parts of a webpage (using div)?

Tags: html, frames, reusability

I have several HTML pages that share a menu area. Every time I update the menu area (eg with new "breaking news") I need to update all 10 pages manually.

With frames, they all point to same frame page so I only need to change one page. But I was told frames are bad and I should use divs. Is there a simple way to do this with divs? (preferably without JQuery or Ajax)

Comment: I am not sure how to do this with divs, but it is easy with either PhP (using include) or asp.net (using master pages).

Comment: Is this using only HTML?  Or are you serving your pages using a server-side language like PHP, JSP, ASP, etc?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the pages are all static and you don't have any generation capability from the server side?

Comment: Echoing the above comments - what you're asking for is best accomplished with a tool other than the one you're currently using.  There are answers as simple as a bash script, but there is no free ride answer.  You should probably add more context so that potential answer-writers have a better sense of what constraints you have.

Comment: Yes this is a purely static HTML site at the moment, just some images and text (I know this may sound unreal to you :). I am unwilling to add asp or php just to solve this problem. I will go back to frames if desperate. Just wanted to know if there are better  (and simpler) solutions out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an `iframe`. It still is sort of a frame, but you would avoid a frameset-index-page and if you set borders to 0 and content that fits in you won't even see borders or scroll-bars and it will behave like a `div`

```
<iframe style="border-width:0px;" src="news.html"/>
```

You should use fixed width-heights though to avoid scrollbars. To me its the simplest "html-only"-solution to your problem.

Comment: OK, this is good enough for me. Better than normal frames and simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use jQuery's `load()` function.

You'd have to add the following to the head of each of your pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you'd have to add the following DIV where you want the content to be loaded.

```
<div id="breakingNews"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/news.js"></script>
```

Be sure to edit the link to the `news.js` file.

Then you'd create the `news.js` on your server, and add the following code:

```
$('#breakingNews').load('path/to/breakingnews.html');
```

More about `load()`:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Not the nice solution, but if you really want to have single point of menu definition, include it in the script which includes `setMenu` function and you load the script in every page's head and call a `setMenu` function on every page's body onload, which then sets the menu as innerHTML of the div that you include in every page specifically as a menu placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Client side templating may be a solution if you are trying to avoid server side solutions for dynamically generating your content.

Using ICanHaz.js templating, http://icanhazjs.com/, you could store your html as objects. Then either include them directly as .js files, or make ajax requests for them.